# How to use ImportHTML formula in Google Spreadsheets on user authentication page

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am trying to fetch data from a page using IMPORTHTML formula in Google spreadsheet. This was working till last week.. However, now website has added another layer for user authentication, and user has to login using valid username and password.

This has made IMPORTHTML to return NA instead of valid values. Can someone please assist me how to fetch this data. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code samples you have? Maybe the details of what you are sending in your request and what the response looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets import functions can only access public available web pages.